# DataSets - Class Model - How to get Bool Value from a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C# and ASP.net.  I am a ColdFusion Programmer but I am catching on to ASP.net.

I will give details then ask my question....

I have been able to get it where I call from the Code Behind a Service Layer Class File (or Bussiness Logic Layer) then in that one call a Data Access Layer Class file.  I have been sending back a DataSet from the Data Access Layer then in the Code Behind moving the code to a table so I can read it row by row.

I was looking for a way to get the Boolean values when I am on the Edit screen to set the check boxes to checked when I found this post.

[C# Assigning a value to DataRow["haswhatnots"] = hasWhatnots is awful slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729062/c-assigning-a-value-to-datarowhaswhatnots-haswhatnots-is-awful-slow)

I see a mention that they should...

Alternatively - use a class model instead of a DataTable that sounds great if it is what I think it is.

What is the Best way to do a CRUD screens where you use the Class file to pull back the data and what format should the Data be in?

I am used to in ColdFusion data coming back in a QuerySet and then we can loop through it.  We can convert he query to Array of Structures or and Array of Obects, XML or JSon but I am still running into issues understanding HOW to get the data out of the DataSet when I get it back.  I get String Data fine right now but maybe there is a very simple example with maybe one page...

I want to figure out how to get the Boolean values right now is my current issue.

Thanks for any help,
Nathan

P.S. if there is a better more professional way to do this let me know.  I want to keep using a (Presentation/CodeBehind/Service/Data Access) type of layers.

```
Protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr;

PageService myPage = new PageService();
DataSet ds = myPage.getPages();

int rowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PageID", typeof(Int32)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PageHTMLContent", typeof(String)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NavigationText", typeof(String)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TopMenu", typeof(Boolean)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SubMenu", typeof(Boolean)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DisplayOrder", typeof(Int32)));
ds.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Active", typeof(Boolean)));

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
  dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr[0] = i;
  dr[1] = i.ToString;
  dr[2] = i.ToString;
  dr[3] = i.ToString;
  dr[4] = i;            // Not sure what to do here for the Boolean Value
  dr[5] = i;  // Not sure what to do here for the Boolean Value
  dr[6] = i;
  dr[7] = i;  // Not sure what to do here for the Boolean Value
}

ds.Tables.Add(dt);
foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  PageIDHiddenField.Value = dataRow["PageID"];
  NameTextBox.Text = dataRow["Name"].ToString();
  PageHTMLContentTextBox.Text = dataRow["PageHTMLContent"];
  NavigationTextTextBox.Text = dataRow["NavigationText"];
  TopMenuCheckBox.Checked = dataRow["TopMenu"];           // Not sure what to do here for the Boolean Value
  SubMenuCheckBox.Checked = dataRow["SubMenu"];           // Not sure what to do here for the Boolean Value
  DisplayOrder.Text = dataRow["DisplayOrder"].ToString();
  ActiveCheckBox.Checked = dataRow["Active"];             // Not sure what to do here for the Boolean Value
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast the value to the correct type. Because `dataRow`'s indexer property will return objects of type `object`, you need to cast it to the right type. Therefore, you need to cast it to `Boolean` like so:

```
TopMenuCheckBox.Checked = (bool)dataRow["TopMenu"];
```

To do one loop to iterate over the rows in the `DataSet` you'd do something like:

```
DataSet ds = myPage.getPages();

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    PageIDHiddenField.Value = row["PageID"];
    NameTextBox.Text = (string)row["Name"];
    ...
    TopMenuCheckBox.Checked = (bool)row["TopMenu"];
}
```

You can use `DataRow`'s indexer property to get the specific column.

Comment: I would prefer only iterating over the original DataSet can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure I'll edit my response. Question: Does your dataset always return *one row*? Seems like you're returning per-page config?

Comment: This one does as it is for the Edit Page so if there is something better I can do and pass back from a Class.  I had considered a reader and creating a structure and passing back a sturcture.  What is the best choice to use?

Comment: Using 

TopMenuCheckBox.Checked = (bool)row["TopMenu"]; 

 Is always making the CheckBox Checked. What is wrong?

Comment: I am incorrect in my haste to fix the problem I had left TopMenu in the row check on all of the check boxes so it is working.  Thanks and if you have any other suggestions on things I should do to make my Code more professional please do.  I am working on getting things RIGHT not geting things done.  When I an get things RIGHT then I will worry about getting things done.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Nathan - The only other thing I'd reccommed is that you should encapsulate the data in some class (ex `PageSettings`) and then return it from the `getPages()` method. If it's just a single page, you'd use `PageSettings GetPage()` and if multiple use `List<PageSettings> GetPages()`. This way you're not using *strings* to reference members in your code.

Comment: I like that @TheCloudlessSky I will look into List<PageSettings> and Collection<YourClass> or is this the same thing?

Comment: `Collection<T>` is best suited for when you want to implement your own collection, in your case you should probably use `List<T>` because you just care about a list of some `T`.