# Equivalent of boolean in SQL bit

Tags: c#

I have a column called Cleared and isResolved in database with a type of bit. I am trying to check for changes in the dataset but I have tried `.equals("true")` or `1` but it doesn't seem to work. I am unable to compare it to boolean too.

```
    if (ds.HasChanges(DataRowState.Modified))
    {
        changes = ds.GetChanges();
        foreach(DataTable t in changes.Tables)
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in t.Rows)
            {
                //i need to evalulate this condition
                if ((row["Cleared"].Equals("true")) && row["isResolved"].Equals("true"))
                {
                    builder.Append(row["Postal Code"]);
                    builder.Append(",");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `(bool)row["Cleared"] == true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to (depending on your query) directly cast a bit to a bool.

There is another thread that talks about this at [DataSets - Class Model - How to get Bool Value from a DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308575/datasets-class-model-how-to-get-bool-value-from-a-dataset).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're comparing the Boolean coming off of the row (true or false...no quotes) to string values containing either the word "true" or the word "false". Take the quotes off of those words with the code you have see what that does.